# Mongo aggregation: how to sum multidimensional array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of mongo documents with a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
{ missionsCompleted: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] }
```

I would like my mongo aggregation pipeline to sum/merge the arrays to change them into this simpler array:

```
{ missionsCompleted: [3,6,9] }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can try the `$zip` aggregate operator to transpose the arrays and perform sum of each array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$arrayElemAt` to select specific element from array
- `$zip` to zip all provided array
- `$map` to iterate loop of zipped array of array and sum numbers

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      missionsCompleted: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              inputs: [
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$missionsCompleted", 0] },
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$missionsCompleted", 1] },
                { $arrayElemAt: ["$missionsCompleted", 2] }
              ]
            }
          },
          in: { $sum: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yaPXm_mV7vk)

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely! And thank you for the playground link - that tool will be a great help next time.