# Mongo aggregation: how to sum multidimensional arrays and objects and make them into new fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I have a collection of mongo documents with a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(...),
  date: ISODate('2023-03-16T00:00:00.000Z'),
  parentId: 'Parent1',
  data: [
    {
      childId: 'Child1',
      childType: 'A',
      childData: [
        [
          0, 1, 3, 0, 5, ... // (int)x60
        ], ... // (array(int))x24
      ]
    },
    {
      childId: 'Child1',
      childType: 'B',
      childData: [
        [
          0, 1, 3, 0, 5, ... // (int)x60
        ], ... // (array(int))x24
      ]
    },
    {
      childId: 'Child2',
      childType: 'A',
      childData: [
        [
          0, 1, 3, 0, 5, ... // (int)x60
        ], ... // (array(int))x24
      ]
    }, ...
  ]
}
```

I want my mongo aggregation pipeline to sum/merge an array and change it to this result :

```
{
  parentId: <parentId>,
  A: { // This is childType
    data: [
      <Sum of 30 data>,
      <Sum of 30 data>, ... // int x 48
    ]
  },
  B: {
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried following this link but failed....
[Mongo aggregation: how to sum multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127570/mongo-aggregation-how-to-sum-multidimensional-array?newreg=eeeebe6eb97f4a918fe6a75e4290ba12)

How can I do this?

Comment: If you know the size of you arrays you could something like this and then format it to your expected output. If this is what you want I can made a more detailed answer. https://mongoplayground.net/p/azGrn1EUysr

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply 
The size of the data is too large, so I tried to simply post the question and solve it myself, but it is impossible.
So I applied my actual data to your link.
Can you please help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75790279/mongo-aggregation-how-to-sum-multidimensional-arrays-and-objects-and-make-them

Comment: @RubénVega Can you help? Haven't solved it yet. 

Comment: You can update this post with the new information, instead of making a new one.

Comment: What you are trying to do is complex, I would give it a try later, but maybe in this case is better to do this logic in you programing language. What language are you using? In tags there is mongoose, is it JS?